# Java File constructor - Combine File object with String

Tags: java

By a random I found out that the following code is valid in Java. Eclipse does not show an error and it does not come to a `RuntimeException` while using the programm:

```
File f1 = new File("");
File f2 = new File(f1 + "");
```

Why does that work? `f1` is definitely not a String so why can we combine two different objects with the `+` operator?  File is a **direct** subclass from Object and we can not merge a `String` with a `File` object because that are mainly different objects.  `File` has also an `uri` constructor but why should this be an uri? `File` and `uri` are in technical view from java absolute different objects (again both are **direct** subclasses from object and have no context to each other) so why does this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible because of `String` conversion.  If the operator is `+`, one of the operands is a `String`, and the other is not, then `String` conversion takes place on the operand that isn't a `String`.  It's converted to a `String` by having `toString()` called on it.

The [JLS, Section 5.1.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11), covers this:

> Any type may be converted to type String by string conversion.

...

> Now only reference values need to be considered:
>
> - If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four ASCII characters n, u, l, l).
> - Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the toString method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the result of invoking the toString method is null, then the string "null" is used instead.

Comment: To be precise, the effect is better described as invoking `String.valueOf(...)`, passing the object reference as an argument: it also works for `null` references.